# Session Max Lifetime not lasting for declared value

Tags: php, session, php-ini

I've declared the `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '14400');`. It has to last for 14400 seconds = 240 minutes = 4 hours. But, it only lasts for 24 minutes (the default value of this function).

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting this before or after `session_start();`?

Comment: Any other server users on your machine? Using Debian (they have had a cronjob once to remove session files, don't know if this is still valid).